# Change in `whereis` behavior in 22.04

Tags: command-line, system

It seems like the `whereis` command in jammy jellyfish doesn't like extensions anymore? I have not been able to find any notes online to this effect.  I just want to make sure this isn't a pibcak issue

```
$ docker run ubuntu:20.04 /bin/bash -c "apt update && apt install -y liblapack-dev && whereis liblapack" > whereislapack20.log

$ docker run ubuntu:22.04 /bin/bash -c "apt update && apt install -y liblapack-dev && whereis liblapack" > whereislapack22.log

$ tail -n 1 whereislapack20.log 
liblapack: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.a

$ tail -n 1 whereislapack22.log 
liblapack:
```